# Error during Closing the MS Access application

Tags: ms-access

When i am closing the MS access application (application.mde) i am getting a error and looks like database has been refreshed and gettting a some other records.

Error Messaage : The Expression on unload you entered as the event property setting produced error:datatype mismatch in criteria expression.

Kindly help me on it.

Comment: The Expression on unload you entered as the event property setting produced error:datatype mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Do you have access to .mdb file? This way you could track the error down.

Comment: Yes i have a acess of .mdb file

Comment: Have you recently update to a new version of MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

the OnFormat property of the form /controls might be set to something other than the string "[Event Procedure]", or may not be named as a valid macro.